# codeigniter change language form_validation_lang

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to change the language file for my form_validation_lang in my LanguageLoader.php in my hooks folder like this:

```
class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $siteLang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($siteLang) {
            $ci->lang->load('message',$siteLang);
            $ci->lang->load('form_validation',$siteLang);
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('message','english');
            $ci->lang->load('form_validation','english');
        }
    }
}
```

For my message_lang.php file it works fine, but codeigniter does not load the form_validation_lang.php correctly after changing the language.

In my application folder:

-language
-- english
---message_lang.php
---form_validation_lang.php
--german
---message_lang.php
---form_validation_lang.php

It takes always the form_validation_lang.php file under english. When I change to german it takes the correct message_lang.php file but not the form_validation_lang.php file. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Yab86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages for form_validation are always loaded in language you set in your config.php. To change the language for your form_validation messages, you need to do a little trick, changing the default language like this:

```
$ci->config->set_item('language', $siteLang);
```

Comment: in the config.php is now $config['language'] = 'german'; Do I have to replace it with $ci->config->set_item('language', 'german'); ?

Comment: no, that's only if you have a multi-language site, with default language English and want to change to german on the fly

Comment: Ahhh....now it works. I changed in the config.php to $config['language'] = ''; and in the LanguageLoader  I added $ci->config->set_item('language', $siteLang);  Thanks a lot!

Comment: notice that this creates 'potentially' another problem. For example, if you send an email IN THE SAME REQUEST, the framework tries to load the language/german/email_lang.php. Possible solutions: add all files from the system language folder into your language folder or apply the override again (back the 'english') after the form validation.