# Setting timzone at global level after user login

Tags: php, codeigniter

My application has users from various timezones. I've set up a settings page from which a user can save their timezone preference.

#### THE PROBLEM

I've a Login controller in which I'm fetching the logged in user's timezone value and setting it using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); // value pulled from database
```

But as soon as I redirect from my "Login" controller to "Dashboard" controller, the timezone is being set back to the original default value of `America/Chicago`.

I verified this using

```
date_default_timezone_get(); // prints "America/Chicago"
```

So where should I put the timezone setting code so that it effects the entire application?

PS: I know `index.php` file or `config.php` file is good choice but at those places, I won't have the user's timezone value retrieved from database.

Comment: Unless you mean global for every single user, then it's better to store the user's timezone in session and set on every request

Comment: Yes, global for every single user. Using session and setting in on every request is a tedious task as I've a dozen of controllers being used at the moment. I was hoping to make the change at a single place and be done with it.

Comment: I would set if condition in hook that checks whatever needed to be checked. User's session, location etc. Choice, regarding application requirements would be between `pre_controller` and `post_controller_constructor`. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html#hook-points).

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997583/codeigniter-change-language-form-validation-lang