# Howto override the default language in codeigniter from controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Howto override the default language in codeigniter from controller?

Get the default language:

```
$this->config->item('language');
```

Now, howto set the custom value?

Comment: wi this `$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'spanish');` and in your **application/language/spnaish/form_validation_lang.php**

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997583/codeigniter-change-language-form-validation-lang, maybe that is what you are looking for...

Comment: also this one may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973204/2275490

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
// Temporaly override the default language
$this->config->set_item('language', $tmp_lang);
```